# TS-React cannot dynamic import using ViteJS

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-typescript

**This is how im calling the Function**

```
<DynamicIcon name={"Money"}/>
```

**The function**

```
import React, {lazy, Suspense} from 'react';

export default function DynamicIcon(props: { name: string }) {
    const {name} = props;

    const IconComponent = lazy(() => import(`@mui/icons-material/${name}`));

    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <IconComponent/>
        </Suspense>
    );
}
```

**ERROR On The Browser**
[image: Browser error]

**Tries**

i changed code to:

import(`@mui/icons-material/${name}.js`)

import(`@mui/icons-material/${name}.ts`)

import(`@mui/icons-material/${name}.d.ts`)

**Because in the node-modules:**

[image: in the node-modules]

Comment: Import statements cannot be dynamic as far as I know. Also, icon components are so lightweight you might actually have a bigger overhead trying to load them dynamically. Unless we are talking about loading hundreds of icons...

Answer (score 0):

When I use MUI Icons with Vite I use this on vite.config.js, you could give it a try for the dynamic imports:

```json
        resolve: {
            alias: [
                {
                    find: /^@mui\/icons-material\/(.*)/,
                    replacement: '@mui/icons-material/esm/$1'
                }
            ]
        }
```